# can sendgrid-java version 4.10.2 use on java17?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to develop an application using Spring Boot 3.2, which has long support. For this reason, we will be using java17, but sendgrid-java Prerequisites on github written "java8 or 11".

GitHub sendgrid-java Site :
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java?tab=readme-ov-file#readme

Can it be used on java17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is generally backwards compatible, so that shouldn't be an issue.

The line you're reading is referring to a minimum version of Java.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

I can continue to develop.